# Which one of these two classes requires more memory and why?

Tags: javascript

Which one of these two classes requires more memory and why?

```
function ClassA() {
    var inc = 1;
    this.method = function (b) {
        return b + inc;
    }
}

function ClassB() {
    var inc = 1;
    this.method = function (b) {
        return b + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Why don't you tell us which one you think takes up more memory and why you think that?

Comment: @p.s.w.g homework question o_0? This is JS engine implementation detail. I'd love to take _that_ course.

Comment: If it is homework (and I agree that it sounds like it), I imagine it would be asking conceptually which would require more memory, based on what they'd learned so in class.

Comment: this is a homework. But I didn't know the answer. I even didn't know what to guess. @Benjamin Gruenbaum helped me to see that the first one is really a closure. And now I can understand why it may need more memory.

Comment: @Green that's not true though. If that's the answer then your teacher is __wrong__. It's _impossible_ to say. It's widely incorrect to say that the first one will always take more memory than the second one. It depends on a lot of things. You should not make these optimizations unless you're writing a library or "very hot" tight loop code. There are so many other things that impact performance before closures.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: What's not true? What exactly did the teacher say that's wrong?

Comment: @cookiemonster The teacher said nothing wrong. Saying that the first one takes more memory than the second one is incorrect. (I've edited it since the initial version, not sure if your comment predates that).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yes, you've updated your comment. But again, I really would imagine this is dealing generally with a concept as taught in class rather than the broad possibilities found in the real world. I'm not even convinced that the question was represented accurately since the `var inc` in the second example isn't used.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to tell, it depends on what JavaScript environment you're using as well as a lot of other factors.

In V8 for example, the first one would require creating a closure and would need more memory, but that might change tomorrow or next month. It might also be very different in other engines.

Worth mentioning, please do not perform premature optimization. It is the root of all evil in most cases. There are really tight spots where such an optimization is beneficial but there is usually a lot of lower bearing fruit to reap first.

Comment: More on premature optimization! http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Found it - Good read about closures in V8: http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html . I'd just like to emphasize again that an optimization that identifies the first variable as a constant, gets rid of the closure and inlines it is very possible, even if not done today. Generally, there is still a surprising amount of improving engines can do about closures.

Comment: Also - a related issue: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2206

Comment: *"It is the root of all evil in most cases."* Sounds sort of like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjvQFtlNQ-M

Answer (score 0):

The answer has to be around the difference in the use of `inc` in the first and the use of `1` in the second and the number of bytes required accordingly.